# Optimising Parse.com object creation

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I have a problem with performance on a relatively simple parse.com routine:

We have two classes and we want to make a cross product of them. One class contains a single object of boilerplate for the new objects (description etc.) the other class contains "large" sets (only 1000s of objects) of variable data (name, geopoint etc). Each new object also has some of its own columns not just data from the parents.

To do this, we do a query on the second class and perform an each operation. In each callback, we create and populate our new object and give it pointers to its parents. We call save() on each object (with some then() clauses for retries and error handling) and push the returned promise into an array. Finally we return status inside a when() promise on that array of save promises.

We originally created all the objects and then performed a saveall on them but couldn't get good enough error handling out of it - so we moved to when() with chains of promises with retries.

Trouble is, it's slow. It doesn't feel like the type of thing a nosql database should be slow at so we're blaming our design.

What's the best practice for cloning a bunch of objects from one class to another? or is it possible to get better results from saveAll failures?

My current code *looks* like this:

```
var doMakeALoadOfObjects = function(aJob,aCaller) {

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

return aJob.save().then(function(aJob) {

    theNumTasksPerLoc = aJob.get("numberOfTasksPerLocation");
    if (theNumTasksPerLoc < 1) {
        theNumTasksPerLoc = 1;
    }

    var publicJob = aJob.get("publicJob");
    return publicJob.fetch();

}).then(function(publicJob) {

    var locationList = aJob.get("locationList");
    return locationList.fetch();

}).then(function(locationList) {

    publicReadACL = new Parse.ACL();
    publicReadACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    publicReadACL.setRoleReadAccess("Admin",true);
    publicReadACL.setRoleWriteAccess("Admin",true);

    // Can't create a promise chain inside the loop so use this function.
    var taskSaver = function(task) {

        return task.save.then(function success(){
            numTasksMade++;
        },
         function errorHandler(theError) {
             numTimeOuts++;
             numTaskCreateFails++;
             logger.log("FAIL:  failed to make a task for job " + aJob.get("referenceString") + " Error: " + JSON.stringify(theError));
         });
    };

    var taskSaverWithRetry = function(task) {

        return task.save().then(function() {

            numTasksMade++;
            return Parse.Promise.as();

        }, function(error) {

            logger.log("makeJobLive: FAIL saving task. Will try again. " + JSON.stringify(error));
            numTimeOuts++;

            return task.save().then(function() {

                    numTasksMade++;
                    return Parse.Promise.as();

                }, function(error) {

                     numTimeOuts++;
                     numTaskCreateFails++;
                     logger.log("makeJobLive: FAIL saving task. Give up. " + JSON.stringify(error));
                     return Parse.Promise.as();
                });
        })
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < theNumTasksPerLoc; j++) {
        var Task = Parse.Object.extend("Task");
        var task = new Task();
        task.set("column",stuff);

        // Can't create a promise chain in the loop so use the function above.
        taskSaverArray.push(taskSaverWithRetry(task));
    }
    return Parse.Promise.when(taskSaverArray);

}).then(function() {


}).then(function() {

    // happy happy

},function(error){
    // we never land here. 
});
}
```

..."looks" like because I've deleted a lot of the object creation code and some housekeeping we do at the same time. I may have deleted some variable definitions too so I doubt this would run as is.

Comment: what about, grouping + `saveAll` with promise in series fashion.

Comment: The problem is that if saveAll fails (and it does) partway through the "all" bit it doesn't give any clue about how far it got. I then thought "ok so in the saveAll error handler find all the records it did create, subtract them from the original set then save again but it feels like awfully complicated code.

Comment: What about whenever a toSave list failed then split it to smaller piece and retry saveAll in series again? And can't you prevent the error before save process?

Comment: What do you mean by slow? Taking CPU time (your javascript code being slow) or IO time (database being slow)?

Comment: "cloning a bunch of objects from one class to another" could mean any number of things. Besides, server-side inefficiencies (eg something for which your NOSQL is not adept) are likely to dominate client-side cloning inefficiencies.

Comment: @Esailija "slow" is more than a few minutes to create 1000 objects. Of course, anything in parse land that takes more that 15 seconds is "slow" because of the cloud function limits.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I thought my explanation covered it in more detail let me know what would make it clear. If there was some way to profile parse cloud code, that would be helpful in diagnosing this.

Comment: @eth3lbert the saveall function can fail for reasons beyond my control specifically Parse can fail for "that's too expensive".